# Why do maven-release-plugin change pom.xml formatting?

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

I'm using `maven-release-plugin` version 2.4.1, and after executing goal `mvn release:prepare -DpreparationGoals="clean deploy -Dmaven.test.skip"`
I found that not only version of my application has been changed, but also it adds a space in confuguration in `maven-antrun-plugin`:

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <configuration>
              <tasks>
                <delete includeEmptyDirs="true" dir="com.project.HelloWorld"/>
              </tasks>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

Space added right between `"com.project.HelloWorld"` and slash. Issue lies in that fact, that `xml-format-plugin` remove this space after Maven build, but after each release I see this annoying space again.

Does anybody know why this happened or how to overcome this issue?

Comment: Why is the a xml-format-plugin related to the maven-release-plugin? apart from that you should use a more recent version of [maven-release-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/) Furthermore calling `release:prepare` you don't need to call preparation goals etc..

Comment: What is the issue with having a space between `HelloWorld"`and `/>` ?

Comment: We have a check in Jenkins pipeline, that after build repository should not contain any untracked changes, because this may break Sonar code analysis step. So this space, which appearing after release, break Jenkins pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Extensible Markup Language (XML) 1.0 (Fifth Edition) – 3.1 Start-Tags, End-Tags, and Empty-Element Tags](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-starttags) a white space character is absolutely OK:

> *Tags for Empty Elements*
>
> [44] `EmptyElemTag` ::= `'<' Name (S Attribute)* S? '/>'` [WFC: Unique Att Spec]

Annoying or not is a matter of POV, IMHO. I personally prefer them.

Comment: I'm not discussing that it's valid or not (i'm fully concur with your opinion),  but i'm trying to find why this plugin do such formatting? It's broking our build\release pipeline, so...

Comment: @stinger I see. I didn't see your according comment before I created my answer, so...